# Garbage Collection and Memory Visualizer (GCMV) Doesn't Always Generate A Report

Tags: java, ibm, websphere

I'm using GCMV within ISA 4.1 to analyze some gc logs from a cluster. When I open a `native_stderr.log` file in that tool, it always creates the following 4 reports/tabs:

- Table data
- Line plot
- Structured Data
- native_stderr.log

These reports are useful, but they don't summarize much and only one of them (Line Plot) can actually be filtered based on date and time.

What is *really* useful is when the tool also generates a summary report with recommendations and a filterable table of high-level stats. However, for whatever reason the GCMV tool doesn't always generate this report. It usually seems to be created for 20% of the files that I analyze, and it's not even consistently generated for the same file twice.

Is there some way that I can force GCMV to create the summary report every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually asked someone at IBM about this and was told two things:

- ISA 4.x really isn't officially supported any more, so I'm going to have trouble getting any help.
- Most of the experts at IBM use [PMAT](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=22d56091-3a7b-4497-b36e-634b51838e11) (IBM Pattern Modeling and Analysis Tool for Java Garbage Collector) anyways, so why don't I try that?

I did and am VERY happy with it. It's very lightweight and fast and gives me MUCH more information than I was getting with GCMV. And the best part is that it is a **standalone tool** that does **not** require ISA, so I don't have to go through the hassle of installing ISA 5.x.